# Elasticsearch throws error about malformed wildcard query even though query follows documentation

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm writing a simple elasticsearch query but cannot get the elasticsearch to accept a simple query like this (copied from my node console running typescript):

```
{
  query: {
    wildcard: {
      name: {
        value: 'begin*'
      }
    },
    bool: {
      must: [
        {
          term: {
            'companyId.keyword': 'KEYWORD'
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   } 
}
```

2 things to note:

1.) the bool section of the query will work and get results on its own
2.) I followed the documentation of wildcards here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

However, when I make the query, I get this response:

`[wildcard] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]`

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the wildcard section inside the bool. If you want to match both the wildcard and the term query, they should be in the "must" list, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "name": {
              "value": "begin*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "companyId.keyword": "KEYWORD"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```